# Focus rectangle for input button on IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer

On IE11 the focus rectangle is very noticable..
I reviewed my css file and couldn't find any related style..
.
[image: Focus Problem]

Does anyone encounter this? How can I solve it? 
This focus rectangle is not present on earlier IE versions....
UPDATE:
Thanks to @Tim B James I have modified the css:

```
  input[type="submit"],
  input[type="button"],
  button {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
    outline: 0;
   }

   input:focus, textarea:focus,
    input[type="submit"]:focus,
    input[type="button"]:focus,
    button :focus {
        border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
        outline-style: dotted;
        outline-width: thin;
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this the css style `outline: none;`?

Comment: It affects but now there is no focus rectangle at all...

Comment: you should be able to add your own focus styling using `.myelement:focus{ border: 1px solid red; }` for example.

Comment: input:focus,input[type="button"]:focus,button :focus {
            border: 1px solid #7ac0da;outline-style: dotted;         outline-width: thin;box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #555;
        } not working...

Comment: set `outline:none` also

Comment: For focused buttons I do want a focus rectangle but more delicate and aesthetic than IE put by default. With outline:none it removed the focus frame for good and this is not what I intended...

Comment: You should explain, in the question itself, what you actually want. The focus rectangle is a usability and accessibility feature. Do you want to remove it, or change it (how?)?

Comment: I want to change it back to what is used to be in earlier versions of IE. On earlier versions it looked like "dotted 1px". On the picture you can see that it looks different on IE11.

Comment: FYI, you can inspect the element in the F12 tools and you can examine the CSS applied to the element. There are several views of the applied CSS available so you can see how the rules cascade, including the browser's default rules. This will help you diagnose issue like this.

Comment: @ChrisLove Thank you for saying the obvious. I did this but IE11 behaves differently with focus and you don't see it with developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Use `outline: none` in your CSS rules for those buttons (or specify a different, less noticeable, outline).  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: @Yaron then style it on focus e.g. `input[type="button"]:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #555; }`.